# Easiest Way to Fire Queries In magento (Entity attribute value model)?

Tags: php, database, database-design, magento, magento-1.5

I am new to Magento and its EAV Model. I am very much confused about its database structure. It's really hard to find data inside tables even when I browse through phpmyadmin. Then it becomes more complicated and time consuming when I try to write queries to fetch data from its tables.

Is there any simple way to understand and deal with this type of database? And is there any simple way to fire queries in it. I tried hard searching internet to get some good tutorials to understand this kind of database but couldn't find. Can anyone suggest any good book or online material to understand Magento database and EAV Model? Thanks

Comment: The first thing you should do is learn how to use a Magento Collection. A collection is basically a nice way to query the Magento database to get just about anything that you need. It extends Zend_Db so you can get to that if you need a little more flexibility (but do as much as you can in the native collection. Once you have figured collections out out, your life will be much better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest taking a look at http://www.alanstorm.com/category/magento and reading through the Model sections. One of the best tutorial/learning sites I've found out there for Magento.